# How do I write a script which runs 5 other scripts from the same folder sequentially?

Tags: python

I have five separate .py files in the same folder and I would like to write a Python script to get all of them to run sequentially with a period of 130 seconds in between each of the runs. What would be the required code for all of this? (assuming the files are file1.py, file2.py, etc)

Comment: Instead of asking for the code directly, I would encourage you to search around for some answers. I would look into importing modules in Python for running multiple scripts inside each other as well as [time.sleep()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/) for the waiting bit you described.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each script has a `main` function (or whatever name you like), you can do something like:

```
import time
import file1
import file2

file1.main()
time.sleep(130)
file2.main()
time.sleep(130)
```

etc.